# Why does God inform mankind that animals are to eat green plants in Genesis 1:30? Does this imply that instinctively they were eating something else

Tags: hebrew

Animals eat based on instinct, so naturally that would be eating plants.  But man has to be told they should eat plants.  Can one infer they already were eating each other, and if so, and clearly not done as part of God’s will, then was Satan already actively doing something which made animals eat each other?  Was Satan possibly already acting in the world through the only mechanism he could use to try to create mankind to worship him…natural selection and evolution.  But evolution didn’t work except for making animals eat each other before the fall in Genesis 3.   Is this why man needed to subdue the earth…it was already acting to kill itself through what Satan was doing?

> Gen 1:30 - And to every beast of the earth and every bird of the air
> and every creature that crawls upon the earth—everything that has the
> breath of life in it—I have given every green plant for food.” And it
> was so.

Comment: In Romans 1, it says through creation, God is demonstrating His invisible attributes and divine nature.  If that is the case, and Satan claimed he could make himself be like the most high God, then could God not be using creation as a time to demonstrate the fallacy of Satan’s claim.  After all, if Satan can’t make what God can make, then He can’t make himself be in essence what God is.  God creates.  Satan can only manipulate. So, could evolution be how Satan tries to mimic God, but all that happens is the creation of subspecies within kinds that eat each other instead of plants.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

There are several points about this:

1. Satan had no influence on earth before or during creation week; therefore, Satan's effect is not even germane.  We are specifically told in Isa 44:24 that God created alone:

> Thus says the LORD, your Redeemer who formed you from the womb: “I am
> the LORD, who has made all things, who alone stretched out the
> heavens, who by Myself spread out the earth

2. The statement in Gen 1:30 is simply the Hebrew way of saying that God made things that way. That is, the original "instinct" for all animals was to eat plant material.
3. The statement in Gen 1:30 is not addressed to mankind - it is a divine edict addressed to nature as part of the creation act.
4. It is only after the flood that animals and mankind are allowed to eat flesh and are thus given the Noahide covenant recorded in Gen 8:20 - 9:17 which included strict rules about what and how flesh could be eaten.
5. "Evolution" is not germane to the Genesis account

Comment: 1.  You said Satan had no influence before or during creation week.   Is that true, or is that an inference based on a set of presuppositions.  In Ezekiel 28, if the King of Tyre is actually a reference to Satan and his fall, then the prophet reveals that he was cast to the ground and placed before kings.  In Genesis 1: 28-30, God essentially commands mankind to go out into the world and subdue and rule over it as His regents.   In essence, mankind is acting on behalf of the king as its ruler.  So, Satan might well be on the earth at this time well before Genesis 3.

Comment: Does the Bible actually say Satan had no influence on the earth during the creation week, or is that an inference based on presupposition?  I don’t know of a verse that says He only shows up in Genesis 3, and as just stated, Ezekiel 28 might actually demonstrate that he is as early as Genesis 1.  Also, does Satan have to be on the earth to have an impact on it.  Satan is not here now in a physical sense, and yet, he can move about looking for those he might devour.  Seemingly, Satan can impact the physical earth without being physically here.

Comment: In your 2nd and 3rd points, you say animals just instinctively eat plants and that the statement is addressed to animals, not mankind.  It seems interesting to me that God would note at all that animals were to eat plants if they already were as a matter of instinct through creation.   I’m not sure I would dismiss the statements mention so quickly as it is extremely odd that God would find reason to make it.  Couldn’t it possibly be that God is telling man this because animals are behaving differently, and this is part of what mankind is sent out to “subdue.”

Comment: Evolution is not germane to the Genesis account.  Perhaps, but it is interesting that the kinds of animals and plants listed as being created during the creation days actually correspond with the most contemporary life forms on each evolutionary branch.   Is it possible, God is acting in more of a punctuated equilibrium style in which He gives Satan and long period of time to create the next step in the development of life on the planet.  He fails through evolution to do anything more than make things that eat each other.  God then acts in one day to move life forward the next step.

Comment: @GregRogers - this is not a site for speculation - it is a site about the text of Scripture as we have it.  Thus, speculation about any attempt to fuse evolution with the Genesis account is off-topic.  The Genesis account simply says that animals were created (as herbivores) on the 5th and 6th days, not before.  All the creation is by divine fiat and edict.  Satan was not involved; Isa 44:24.

Comment: The statement in 1:30 is a general edict not addressed to man? Since it spoken to the man and woman who God have given dominion over the animals, isn't it instruction to man? IOW, you have dominion over the animals I have created and given green plants for them to eat?

Comment: @RevelationLad - the final clause precludes this: "And to every beast of the earth and every bird of the air and every creature that crawls upon the earth—everything that has the breath of life in it—I have given every green plant for food.” **And it was so.**

Comment: So God cannot give man this command because it reflects God’s desire?

Comment: @RevelationLad - the command was not given to mankind but it was a creative declaration - mankind cannot make animals what they are not

Comment: Your reasoning is a little out of order. 1. God, not man makes animals what they are. 2. God creates man to have dominion over the animals God created. 3. God tells man he has been given dominion over the animals. 4. God instructs man that the animals have been created to live by eating green plants.

Comment: @RevelationLad - God's instruction to Adam and Eve finishes at the end of V28.  "And God said ... " of V29 is a new edict to someone else and finishes with "And it was so.."